# tar command from busybox 1.18.4 goes into hang condition after disabling USE_BB_PWD_GRP option from busybox

Tags: linux, authentication, tar, busybox

I have busy-box 1.18.4 package in my system.

I have disabled USE_BB_PWD_GRP option to work with /etc/nsswitch.conf to solve some user logging related issues .

After Disabling that option from busy-box , tar utility from busy-box is not working and goes into hang condition after that.

so does any one have idea about this issue or does any one have faced this issue before?

Please let me know as soon as possible if any one knows this issue.

Comment: does any one have idea about this issue? Please let me know if any one knows about this issue...

Comment: Is it a complete hang or after 3 minutes tar proceeds? May be it is irrelevant, but just to be sure try to use "arp" and "arp -n" commands. If "arp" hangs, then it could be due to bad hostnames resolution.

Comment: It is little bit hang for 5 to 10 minutes and comes out after that amount of time from tar command execution while executing tar command to extract compressed tar file. We will try to execute "arp" command at our side and let you know the result as soon as possible. So, You mean that it is related to hostname mapping that you are telling. Correct?

Comment: getaddrinfo(3)/gethostbyname(3) functions could lead to long timeout in some circimstances (as far as I remember - if there is no route to DNS, but system can't detect this locally), especially if a program calls them multiple times before giving up. One example is arp (-n prevents address to name resolution), second (surprisingly) - midnight commander (https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/3082). So there is a chance that tar calls, maybe indirectly, some resolver functions.

Comment: ok. i will look into this hostname resolution mechanism at our side and let you know the reult of tar command hang issue which we are facing at our side.